# Hide query params from the url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

From one component i navigate to another component and i pass some params. Also i want to pass query params but i dont want it to be seen in url. I tried using skiplocationchange but then that works but the url doesnt change when we navigate from parent to child. So i dont want to use skiplocationchange.

```
this._router.navigate(['/detailReports',id],{queryParams:{reportName : name},queryParamsHandling:"merge"});
```

So here reportName  i just want it to be there in router so that i can get this prop later. But i dont want it to be shown in the url.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to obfuscate the params. But you could use a singleton service to share the variable instead. It wouldn't be shown in the URL.

Comment: @MichaelD so basically i want to pass some data to router component. So is there any other way to do instead of service. I googled and found that we can use [state]="{ orderId: 1234 }" but i am not sure if this is the right way to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can like this :

fromPage:

`this.router.navigate(['/detailReports],{state:params})`

toPage:

`constructor(){ let params = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras["state"] ? this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras["state"] : ""`
} `